# how to get the longest animation

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-animate

I'm having loads of divs in an array which I `.fadeIn()` randomly.

Within the last cube, which I animate seperatly to use the return function I want to fire another function:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 800; i++) {
  getCube(i).animate({ opacity: 1}, Math.floor(Math.random()*1000)});
  if (/* next to last cube is done with animation */)
       { getCube(799).animate({ opacity: 1}, 500, function() {
          // some function
        });
  }
}
```

The problem is, how can get the moment when the longest `animate()` is done to start the last animate.

Hope you get my point. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the brightest solution but might work:

```
var durations = [],
    _durations,
    _greatest;

for (var i = 0; i < 800; i++) {
    var duration = Math.floor(Math.random()*1000);
    durations.push(duration);
}

_durations = durations;
_durations.sort(function(a,b){return b-a});
_greatest = _durations[0];

for (var i = 0; i < 800; i++) {
  var _duration = durations[i];
  getCube(i).animate({ opacity: 1}, _duration});
  if (i == 798)
       { getCube(798).stop().animate({ opacity: 1}, _greatest, function() {
          // some function
        });
  }
}
```

The idea is to write all the fade duration times in an array and get the greatest out of it to use it later. Does that help you?

Comment: yes, you didnt say about starting the animations at different timings. The duration of the animation is different, not the beginning